# How to import an existing data factory ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I went to an existing data factory, and chose to `export template`:

[image]

I then manually created a new data factory, and now I am trying to import the existing data factory to this new one, by going to the new one, and selecting `import template`:

[image]

However, this leads us to a generic page:

[image]

**How do we publish or import a data factory using the same templates as were generated when we exported the data factory?**

Answer (score 5):

Unzip the file you got when you hit "Export ARM Template" in ADF.

If you hit "Build your own template in the editor" you can then click "Load file" to upload the file named "arm_template.json" from the zip, then hit "Save" at the bottom.

Then click the "Edit Parameters" button and upload the "arm_template_parameters.json" file the same way as above, change the "factoryName" field' value to the desired factory and hit "Save" again.

Note: If you have any passwords or other hidden credentials you will have to re-enter them.

You should be all set to hit purchase and you will be able to create your ADF Factory from the ARM templates.

Answer (score 1):

This doc shows how to do continuous integration and delivery in Azure Data Factory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment

Answer (score -2):

Click on `Build your own template in the editor` and paste the entire content of the exported `armtemplate.json` file and that should work

Comment: it's not just 1 file. it's 1 arm template, another file for parameters for it, and then another linked arm template and parameters for it, so its 4 total within some folder structure

Comment: then try to deploy it from PowerShell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#example-templates