# Migrate Azure Data Factory from one account to another account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have two Azure accounts with different subscriptions, consider 'A' data factory is old account and 'B' data factory is new account. 'A' data factory is configured with azure devops git and i want to clone/migrate the 'A' data factory Of old account to 'B' data factory of new account. Any help how to migrate the Azure Data Factory from old to new account?

Need migration steps in migrating the azure data factory from one account to another account

Answer (score 0):

Move Data Factory to a new region. If you want to move your Data Factory to a different region, the best way is to create a copy in the targeted region, and delete the existing one.

[Copy or clone a data factory in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-clone-data-factory#use-cases-for-cloning-a-data-factory)

[export and import using ARM templates](https://youtu.be/JUjDlSfs_nY?t=240)

Export and import pipeline template.
[image: Export template]

Comment: Is this approach works? old data factory ARM templates are stored in adf_publish. approach is clone old git account to new git account then configure new git account with newly created azure devops then through azure devops can I export ARM templates to newly created data factory

Comment: ARM template will import into new data factory. 

https://datamajor.net/how-to-export-import-an-azure-data-factory-arm-template/#:~:text=Importing%20the%20ADF%20ARM%20template&text=After%20clicking%20on%20%E2%80%9CImport%20on,you%20exported%20the%20ARM%20template.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445138/how-to-import-an-existing-data-factory-arm-template